# О 1 000 персоналиЯХ или персоналИЙ?

Tags: числительные, множественное-число, существительные

На *Грамоте*:

1. Правильно: *в 700 000 (семистах тысячах) организацИЙ.*
2. Правильно: *более чем о 1 000 персоналиЯХ*.
3. Правильно: *прибор, украшенный 5 000 кристаллОВ*.

Так как же будет правильно?

Answer (score 3):

По поводу пункта 2. Та же Грамота ([«Тысяче работникам» или «тысяче работников»?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/61-rubric-92)) приходит в выводу, что правильно писать "тысяче работников", то есть "тысяча" является здесь именем существительным, которое управляет родительным падежом существительного "работники".

Аналогично должно быть "о 1 000 персоналий". Почему Грамота противоречит сама себе - не знаю.

Остальные пункты возражений не вызывают.

Comment: Согласен насчёт всего и второго пункта в частности!